# Is there a findOne operation in the Mongo C driver?

Tags: mongodb, mongo-c-driver

MongoDB implements a[`findOne()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/) collection operation.

However, looking into the [collection operations available in the Mongo C driver](http://mongoc.org/libmongoc/1.17.4/mongoc_collection_t.html) I haven't found it there. It's a bit surprising, as other drivers implements it (such as [the C++ driver](http://mongocxx.org/api/mongocxx-3.6.2/classmongocxx_1_1collection.html#a7bc5c6087f55bf9a26b11f85c5ffe2c4)).

Interestingly, I have found in the Mongo C driver code repository [a kind of implementation for a findOne function](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-c-driver/blob/764050ed11bbf4fc611c5cab17479be5e734588b/src/libmongoc/tests/json-test-operations.c#L1471). However it seems it is in a part of the code related with the tets...

Thus, is the Mongo C driver providing a `findOne()` operation? Or do I need to implement it myself (maybe using [mongoc_collection_find_with_opts](http://mongoc.org/libmongoc/1.17.4/mongoc_collection_find_with_opts.html) setting limit to 1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you located is indeed used for executing tests (cross-driver ones) which do contain a `findOne` operation.

Based on this I would say the C driver doesn't provide a `findOne` operation and you are meant to use something like the `find_one` function you found to get a  single document out of the cursor returned from `mongoc_collection_find_with_opts`.